# What is a good strategy for safely reading values out of a PHP array?

Tags: php

I'm trying to read values from $_SESSION which may or may not be set, while avoiding undefined index warnings.  I'm used to Python dicts, which have a `d.get('key','default')` method, which returns a default parameter if not found.  I've resorted to this:

```
function array_get($a, $key, $default=NULL)
{
  if (isset($a) and isset($a[$key]))
    return $a[$key];
  else
    return $default;
}

$foo = array_get($_SESSION, 'foo');
if (!$foo) {
  // Do some foo initialization
}
```

Is there a better way to implement this strategy?

Comment: why do you want global variables out of session? why not to use $_SESSION members itself? At leas give them another names, not matching $_SESSION array indexes or there can be some troubles

Comment: Only a tip: You can use `isset($a, $a[$key])` instead of `isset($a) && isset($a[$key])`.

Comment: Col. Shrapnel - I'm new to PHP.  Can you explain further?  Maybe give an example of using $_SESSION members instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `array_key_exists` instead of `isset` for the second condition.  Isset will return false if `$a[$key] === null` which is problematic if you've intentionally set `$a[$key] = null`.  Of course, this isn't a huge deal unless you set a `$default` value to something other than `NULL`.

```
function array_get($a, $key, $default=NULL)
{
  if (isset($a) and array_key_exists($key, $a))
    return $a[$key];
  else
    return $default;
}
```

Comment: On the other hand `array_key_exists` involves a function call. Furthermore many people want `null` to be treated as `unset`.

Comment: I guess subtleties like this is why there isn't One True Solution built into PHP.

Comment: @nikic - OP stated that they were used to the Python dict.get() method.  This is a more accurate representation of that functionality where if the key, value pair is `'a':None` and you called `x.get('a', 'a null value')` the return would be `None` and NOT `'a null value'`

Answer (score 2):

```
$foo = (isset($_SESSION['foo'])) ? $_SESSION['foo'] : NULL;
```

Comment: I was expecting an "Undefined variable" warning if the session wasn't started, but I didn't get it (PHP 5.3.1).  I guess `isset()` handles both "Undefined variable" and "Undefined index" warnings.